# File "vkbot.py", line 11 return ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

```
import vk_api
import requests

session = requests.Session()
login, password = 'тут мой номер телефона', 'тут мой пароль'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
try:
vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
    return

from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:            
        if event.text == 'Помоги, пожалуйста.':
            if event.from_user:
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id=event.user_id,
                    message='Чем могу помочь?'
                )
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, не знаю, в чём трабл и как пофиксить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У Вас в 11 строчке `return`. Использовать его можно только в функциях.

Comment: Уточните, какого эффекта Вы хотели бы добиться?

Answer (score 0):

В 11 строчке Вы используете инструкцию `return` вне функции.

Если Вы хотите завершить программу, то Вам может помочь `quit()`, `exit()`, `sys.exit()` и др.

***Пример:***

```py
...
try:
    vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
    quit()
...
```

---

Есть и другие ошибки:

- не инициализирован `longpoll`
- не инициализирован `vk` (объект для доступа к `API`)

*Следует добавить в код:*

```py
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

Также обратите внимание, что Ваш код не следует `PEP-8`.

---

**UPD:**
Даже с правками выше, Вы не добьётесь желаемого результата, вернётся:

```html
[15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

ВК ограничили доступ к `User Long Poll API` ([*issue 219*](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues/219)).